# Easy way to concatenate several matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, rbind, cbind

Is there an easy way to build a matrix in R based on several other block matrix?

Suppose that I have A1,A2,A3 and A4 matrix. I want to construct a Matrix A that is the equivalent in matlab of [A1,A2;A3;A4]. I know that i could use rbind(cbind(A1,A2),cbind(A3,A4)), is there a more efficient and direct way?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But generally in R you need to use `rbind` and `cbind` to combine matrices. You could write your own function to make it easier, but as far as base options go that's kind of it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you find inefficient about your `rbind()` / `cbind()` approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R doesn't really have a lot of shortcut notations for creating matrices like matlab. The most explicit it just to stick with the `rbind` and `cbind` as you've already done. If it's something you find yourself doing a lot, you could write a helper function like this

```
mat_shape <- function(expr) {
  env<-new.env(parent=parent.frame())
  env[[":"]] <- base::cbind
  env[["/"]] <- base::rbind
  eval(substitute(expr), envir = env)
}
```

here we re-refine `:` to be cbind and `/` to be rbind for this particular function input. Then you could do

```
A <- matrix(1:6, ncol=3)
B <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
C <- matrix(1:3, ncol=1)
D <- matrix(1:12, ncol=4)

mat_shape(A:B/C:D)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    5    1    3
# [2,]    2    4    6    2    4
# [3,]    1    1    4    7   10
# [4,]    2    2    5    8   11
# [5,]    3    3    6    9   12
```